# Lightweight NAS distro

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, low-memory, distro, lightweight

I'm looking for a free + lightweight NAS distro that could run nicely on a low spec *Icybox* (see http://www.raidsonic.de/en/products/nas-systems.php?we_objectID=6853)

> Storlink3516, Arm9 300 Mhz
>
> 128mb RAM

For general storage, backups and a git/ VC server.

Only thing I came across that matched the description, was [hotnas](http://code.google.com/p/hotnas/), which seems pretty dead o_0

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

My RaspberryPI with 256 MB RAM occupies about 50-80 megabytes with Debian ARM distribution with 2 services : samba and transmission-daemon so 128 MB will be enough in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Debian should be sufficient. Check out [this guide](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/orion/qnap/ts-209/) for installation tips, although I am not sure if all steps will apply to your hardware.